# how to check the height of an element in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, meteor

I want to check the height of the element "content" in javascript. The issue is there can be multiple "content"s with different heights in a single page and hence cannot use the "class=contentMain" in javascript(or atleast I think in that way).
  Html code

```
    <template name="pT">
    <ul style="list-style-type:none" class="pcl">
        {{#each Contents}}
            {{>pI}}
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
    </template>      
    <template name="pI">
      <p class="bucket">
        <li class= "contentMain">{{{content}}}</li>
      </p>
   </template>
```

I want to use a helper function to check the height of the "content' element in javascript.

```
 Template.pI.helpers({
    $('.contentMain').height;
});
```

Apologies for diverting from any programming conventions.
Any help would be hugely appreciated

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to use an ID, assign one to the content box that you would like to measure the height of.

```
<li class= "contentMain">{{{content}}}</li>
```

becomes

```
<li id="contentMain" class="contentMain">{{{content}}}</li>
```

JS:

```
  Template.pI.helpers({
    $('#contentMain').height();
   });
```

Without an ID:

```
$("li").each(function () {
   if ($(this).hasClass('contentMain')) {
       var height = $(this).height();
   }  
});
```

Comment any parts that aren't applicable and I will adjust my answer :)

Comment: I believe that i cannot use "id" here because there are going to be several contents in a single page

Comment: @SujoyDe Updated my answer, let me know if the new solution works.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you want to do with this? You could do this:

```
Template.pI.helpers({
    myHelper: function () {
        var tmpl = Template.instance();
        return tmpl.$('.contentMain').height();
    }
})
```

Comment: and what do you want to do with this height value?

Comment: I want to check if the height is greater than 60 px. If it is then I want to put class big instead of contentMain

Comment: hmmm you need to do this after the template is rendered so in onRendered (http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_onRendered) hook, you could use the jQuery to iterate through items

Answer (score 0):

```
var clientHeight = document.getElementsByClassName("contentMain")[0].clientHeight;
```

or

```
var offsetHeight = document.getElementsByClassName("contentMain")[0].offsetHeight;
```

The `offsetHeight` property is similar to the `clientHeight` property, but it returns the height including the padding, scrollBar and the border.

Comment: one general confusion:- I have not used any "id" in my html file. So how is it gong to solve the problem?

Comment: @SujoyDe I've edited my answer, I believe that it will work as well

Comment: sorry for asking again but what is the function of [0] after contentMain. Thanks for answering

Comment: @SujoyDe `document.getElementsByClassName()` returns a collection of items since you can have mulitple classes, the `[0]` selects the first occurance of the class

Comment: @SujoyDe Since you'll have multple of these on your page, this comes in handy because you can change it to `[1]` if you want the second occurance

Comment: There is an error coming:- cannot read property client height of undefined at console

Comment: @SujoyDe Did you copy the code directly from my answer, I'm asking this because there was an error in there I accidentally put a semicolon **`;`** in the middle of the line, if you copy it now it should work

Comment: I corrected that and I put it there. For some reason it is showing that error

Comment: @SujoyDe I've spotted the problem, edited the line in answer again, I had put a dot **`.`** before the `contentMain` in the `getElementsByClassName()`

Comment: This pI template is in another template which is running an "each" function and that is why i cannot use the class in this way.